# iOS SceneKit application faster in App Switcher Mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I'm encountering a rather bizarre behavior with a SceneKit application that I am developing. I invoke a method which manipulates the `simdWorldPosition` property of  various `SCNNode` objects. The method changes the `simdWorldPosition` in a loop which can execute around ~40k times.

I define a `DispatchQueue`:

```swift
let updateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! +
        ".serialSceneKitQueue")
```

A button press calls the following:

```swift
@objc func didPressGreedy() {
    updateQueue.async {
        let _ = self.Greedy()
    }
}
```

```swift
autoreleasepool {
    for offset in stride(from: 0.0, through: planeWidth, by: increment) {
        var topLeftTransform = arkitAnchor!.simdWorldTransform * HelperMethods.makeTranslationMatrix(tx: -Float(planeWidth / 2), ty: 0.0, tz: -Float(planeHeight/2))
        topLeftTransform = topLeftTransform * HelperMethods.makeTranslationMatrix(tx: Float(offset), ty: 0.0, tz: 0.0)
        let topEdgePosition = simd_float3(x: topLeftTransform.columns.3.x, y: topLeftTransform.columns.3.y, z: topLeftTransform.columns.3.z)
        saLabelComponent.simdWorldPosition = topEdgePosition

        let oldSpriteTransform = sprite.simdWorldTransform

        for xOffset in stride(from:-0.20, through: 0.20, by: increment) {
            for yOffset in stride(from: 0.05, through: 0.20, by: increment) {
                LOOP_1_ITERATIONS += 1
                var newSpriteTransform = anchor.simdWorldTransform * HelperMethods.makeTranslationMatrix(tx: Float(xOffset), ty: Float(yOffset), tz: 0.0)
                sprite.simdWorldTransform = newSpriteTransform
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These iterations are slow - I can sometimes see about a thousand manipulations happen in multiple seconds and then it takes a minute to do 50 `simdWorldPosition` updates. If I tap on the screen I can see the executions speed up.

When I use the iOS App Switcher (by just swiping up on the application on iPhone XS and letting it sit in the App Switcher) the application significantly speeds up the execution the iterations by a factor of 10x.

Any idea of why this is caused? If I am having conceptual issues please point to relevant topic/articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea of why this is caused?

It sounds like your app is simply doing a lot less work when in switcher. That's not surprising... the area that the app draws into is *much* smaller, there are no touch events to handle, etc. The difference may have less to do with the code in the loop you've shown than in the fact that the rest of the app isn't doing as much.

If you really want to know what's going on (or what isn't going on), the best thing to do is to profile your code with Instruments.

Comment: Why exactly would "tapping" on the screen speed up execution?

Comment: @oneiros You didn't say anything about tapping. You said that letting the app sit in switcher makes it run faster. I'm saying that between the smaller drawing area and other reduced responsibilities while in that mode, the app has more time to devote to your code.

Comment: I forgot to put that in the post - for some reason when I tap the perturbations of the `simdWorldPosition` speed up significantly. Any idea, based on your experience, why that would happen?

Comment: @oneiros Depending on the device, iOS version, and settings, the OS may be slowing down the processor when you're not actively interacting. In that case, tapping would create an interaction and cause the OS to speed up the processor again. You can try turning off Low Power Mode in Settings (under Battery).